# Why doesn't the CrawlSpider collect links?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to run my first CrawlSpider, but the program terminates without any errors, while it does not return anything, it terminates with zero result. What's wrong with my code?

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class FagorelectrodomesticoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'fagorelectrodomestico.com'
    allowed_domains = ['fagorelectrodomestico.com']
    start_urls = ['https://fagorelectrodomestico.com']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='product/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    for doc in response.css('a.file'):
        doclink = doc.css('::attr("href")').get()
        product = Product()
        product['model'] = response.css('h2.data__symbol::text').get()
        product['brand'] = 'Fagor'
        product['file_urls'] = [doclink]
        yield product
```

Comment: is this your original code? You have wrong indentations. If in original code you have different indentations then show it in question. Showing wrong indentations can change everything.

Comment: How do you run it? It need to run as `project` or you would have to use `CrawlerProcess()` to run it without `project`

Comment: I can't find `product/` in `HTML` on main page. I see `product/` on subpages (like https://fagorelectrodomestico.com/en/refrigerators) but this code doesn't try to load subpages.

Comment: the biggest problem is that this page uses `JavaScript` to add elements to `HTML` but `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript`, it may need `scrapy-selenium` to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is this page uses `JavaScript` to add all elements to HTML but `Scrapy` can't run `JavaScript`. If you turn off `JavaScript` in browser and reload this page then you should see empty white page. But there is module [scrapy_selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/) which can use module [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript` (but it will run slower).

Other problem: your rule search links with `product/` which I don't see on main page but I can see on pages with categories. But you don't need rule to load other pages and it can't get links `product/`  from subpages - so it needs another rule to get other links and send to callback `parser` (which in `Spider` loads page, searchs all links and checks rules on these links).

And it may need to add `/en/` to starting url to get english version which has links with `product/`. Spanish version has links `productos/`.

Some code needed to use `SeleniumRequest` instead of standard `Request` - I took some code from [source code of CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/spiders/crawl.html#CrawlSpider) and add it with changes.

I also used `CrawlerProcess` to run code without creating project - so everyone can simply copy it and run `python script.py`

It downloads files to folder `full`.

I tested only without option `-headless` to see what it get in browser. You may have to test with `-headless` because it may work faster but sometimes it bahave different.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import scrapy_selenium

class FagorelectrodomesticoSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'fagorelectrodomestico.com'

    allowed_domains = ['fagorelectrodomestico.com']
    start_urls = ['https://fagorelectrodomestico.com/en/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/en/product/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/en/', deny='/en/product/'), callback='parse', follow=True),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        print('[start_requests]')
        for url in self.start_urls:
            print('[start_requests] url:', url)            
            yield scrapy_selenium.SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('[parse] url:', response.url)
        
        for rule_index, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            #print(rule.callback)
            for link in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response):
                yield scrapy_selenium.SeleniumRequest(
                    url=link.url,
                    callback=rule.callback,
                    errback=rule.errback,
                    meta=dict(rule=rule_index, link_text=link.text),
                )
            
    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('[parse_item] url:', response.url)
        
        for doc in response.css('a.file'):
            doclink = doc.css('::attr("href")').get()
            product = {
                'model': response.css('h2.data__symbol::text').get(),
                'brand': 'Fagor',
                'file_urls': [doclink],
            }
            yield product
        

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1

    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},   # used standard FilesPipeline (download to FILES_STORE/full)
    #'FILES_STORE': '/path/to/valid/dir',  # this folder has to exist before downloading
    'FILES_STORE': '.',                   # this folder has to exist before downloading

    'SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME': 'firefox',
    'SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH': '/home/furas/bin/geckodriver',
    #'SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS': ['-headless'], # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
    'SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS': [],
    #'SELENIUM_BROWSER_EXECUTABLE_PATH': '',
    #'SELENIUM_COMMAND_EXECUTOR': '',
    
    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800}
})
c.crawl(FagorelectrodomesticoSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and detailed answer. your consultation helped me a lot to understand the issue... I coped with using splash instead of selenium

Answer (score -1):

From reading the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) it appears that this line could be the issue:

```py
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='product/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)
```

The docs say:

> callback is a callable or a string (in which case a method from the spider object with that name will be used) to be called for each link extracted with the specified link extractor.

Your `parse_item` is a callable, not a method from a spider object. So, I think you should pass it in as a callable:

```py
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='product/'), callback=parse_item, follow=True),
)
```

Since Python reads from top-to-bottom, define `parse_item()` above the `rules` line:

```py
def parse_item(self, response):
    for doc in response.css('a.file'):
        doclink = doc.css('::attr("href")').get()
        product = Product()
        product['model'] = response.css('h2.data__symbol::text').get()
        product['brand'] = 'Fagor'
        product['file_urls'] = [doclink]
        yield product


rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='product/'), callback=parse_item, follow=True),
)
```